# How can I convert hex strings into numbers in Perl?

Tags: perl, hex

I recently wrote a script which parsed a text representation of a single binary byte month field.

(Don't ask :-{ )

After fiddling with sprintf for a while I gave up and did this;

```
our %months = qw / x01 1 
       x02 2
       x03 3 
       x04 4 
       x05 5 
       x06 6 
       x07 7 
       x08 8 
       x09 9 
       x0a 10 
       x0b 11 
       x0c 12 /;
...
my $month = $months{$text};
```

Which I get away with, because I'm only using 12 numbers, but is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: did you mean `0x1` instead of `x01`?

Comment: @Nathan In this particular situation no, but in non-insane situation you probably would want the 0x01, but your answer covered both situations, which is why I accepted it!

Comment: For the other way around, decimal to hexadecimal, see Stack Overflow question *[How to convert decimal to hexadecimal in Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481001)*.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you have

```
$hex_string = "0x10";
```

you can use:

```
$hex_val = hex($hex_string);
```

And you'll get: `$hex_val == 16`

`hex` doesn't require the "`0x`" at the beginning of the string. If it's missing it will still translate a hex string to a number.

You can also use `oct` to translate binary, octal or hex strings to numbers based on the prefix:

- `0b` - binary
- `0`  - octal
- `0x` - hex

Answer (score 9):

See [hex](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/hex.html) and/or [oct](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/oct.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @months = map hex, qw/x01 x02 x03 x04 x05 x06 x07 x08 x09 x0a x0b x0c/;
print "$_\n" for @months;
```

Comment: To expound: "say" is one of the (IMHO questionable) new bits of syntax added to recent perls.  It doesn't work by default, because being new syntax it would break old scripts.  So you use the '-E' argument to run a script with "all" features.  But of course that gets you all features added since your script was written too, which may break it.  Basically, the given example is more about showing off than it is about enginering a solution.  But the answer about the hex function is right.

Comment: @Andy Ross: There is no showing off. One can just use `print "$_\n"` rather than `say`. In the case of the first example, however, using print would have required me to write `print qq{$_\n}` which is obviously more cluttered. Both examples are written to be copied & pasted to the command prompt and for illustration only. There is no script to be broken. If one only wants to use `say` in one's script, one can do `use feature 'say'` or `use Perl6::Say` (available on CPAN). Finally, **what engineering solution???**

Comment: My point was more about -E than say.  The -E argument can't be reliably used for anything, as it doesn't specify a specific language, just "whatever is most recent".   And I don't follow your quoting argument.  You can enclose double quotes inside single quotes on a command line just fine...

Comment: @Andy Ross a plain reading of both your comments leave me puzzled. But, life is too short. No more `-E`, no more `say` even though I think your criticism is vacuous.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly you have 1 byte per month - not string "0x10", but rather byte with 10 in it.

In this way, you should use [unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html):

```
my $in = "\x0a";
print length($in), "\n";
my ($out) = unpack("c", $in);
print length($out), "\n", $out, "\n"
```

output:

```
1
2
10
```

If the input are 3 characters, like "x05", then changing is also quite simple:

```
my $in = "x0a";
my $out = hex($in);
```

Comment: @depesz Your downvotes are simply unjustified. Do you know what the `qw//` operator does in Perl? Do you know what *a text representation of single binary byte* means?

Comment: @Sinan: I know. I guess that OP gave \x01, and not x01 - and the \ was simply lost someplace. please note from his question: "single binary byte month field". not "4 byte string \x01" or "3 byte string"

Comment: @depesz **text representation** of a single binary byte month field. Words must mean something.

Comment: @Sinan - ok. now you made me doubt. Downvotes removed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way that may be more practical for directly converting the hexadecimals contained in a string.

This make use of the /e (e for eval) regex modifier on s///.

Starting from this string:

`$hello_world = "\\x48\\x65\\x6c\\x6c\\x6f\\x20\\x57\\x6f\\x72\\x6c\\x64";`

Hexadecimals to characters :

`print $hello_world =~ s/\\x([0-9a-fA-F]{2})/chr hex $1/gre;`

Hexadecimals to decimal numbers :

`print $hello_world =~ s/\\x([0-9a-fA-F]{2})/hex $1/gre;`

Drop the /r modifier to substitute the string in-place.

One day I used a python script that did stuff with a binary file and I was stuck with a bytes literal (b'\x09\xff...') containing only hexadecimal digits.
I managed to get back my bytes with a one-liner that was a variant of the above.