# How do I convert decimal to hexadecimal in Perl?

Tags: perl

How can I convert a number, `$d = 1024`, in decimal to 0xFF in hex in Perl?

The `d` variable needs to be assigned to a different variable and be printed, so for readability I required it to be in hexadecimal format.

Comment: Just one small hint: 1024 in hex is 0x200 while 0xFF is 255 in decimal.

Comment: For the other way around, hexadecimal to decimal, see Stack Overflow question *[How can I convert hex strings into numbers in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531993)*.

Comment: 1024 = 4 * 256 = 0x400 :  `perl -Mbigint -E 'say 1024->as_hex'` prints 0x400

Comment: For decimal to octal: *[Perl how can I print a character in octal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091384/)* (2013). The gist is using `%o` instead of `%X` with sprintf(). But isn't there a more canonical question?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`1024` in decimal is not `0xFF` in hex. Instead, it is `0x400`.

You can use [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) as:

```
my $hex = sprintf("0x%X", $d);
```

Comment: There is no faster way to do it (for a one liner) ?

Answer (score 30):

Caveat: `sprintf` **overflows** at 2<sup>64</sup> ≅ 10<sup>19</sup>, on 32-bit even already at only 2<sup>32</sup> ≅ 4×10<sup>9</sup>.

For large numbers, enable the lexical pragma [`bigint`](http://p3rl.org/bigint). [`as_hex`](http://p3rl.org/Math%3a%3aBigInt#as_hex) is documented in `Math::BigInt`.

```
use bigint;
my $n = 2**65;
print $n->as_hex;   # '0x20000000000000000'
```

Answer (score 2):

## I put these snippets into Perl files in my $PATH:

#### Convert list of decimal numbers into hexadecimal and binary

```perl
for ($i = 0; $i < @ARGV; $i++) {
    printf("%d\t= 0x%x\t= 0b%b\n", $ARGV[$i], $ARGV[$i], $ARGV[$i]);
}
```

#### Convert list of hexadecimal numbers into decimal and binary

```perl
for ($i = 0; $i < @ARGV; $i++) {
    $val = hex($ARGV[$i]);
    printf("0x%x\t= %d\t= 0b%b\n", $val, $val, $val);
}
```

#### Convert list of binary numbers into decimal and hexadecimal

```perl
for ($i = 0; $i < @ARGV; $i++) {
    # The binary numbers you type must start with '0b'
    $val = oct($ARGV[$i]);
    printf("0b%b\t= %d\t= 0x%x\n", $val, $val, $val);
}
```

Comment: It would be more idiomatic Perl if you used foreach to go through the data elements instead of the C-style for() to go through the array indices.

Comment: "0x%x" will output in lower case. Use "0x%X" for the correct uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the classical **printf()**.

```
printf("%x",$d);
```

Comment: "%x" will output in lower case. Use "%X" for the correct uppercase.