# How can I print a character in octal in Perl?

Tags: perl

How can I print characters with their octal representations? Note that these characters might be special characters (escapes, backscapes, arrow keys, etc.).

For example, I would like a function 'printoctal', such that:

```
my $char = 'P';
printoctal $char;
```

And I would like that to print `120`.

Comment: That was 5 years after the launch of Stack Overflow. What is the canonical question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want two things: `ord` takes a string, and returns the numeric value of that string's first character. That is, `ord "P"` is 80.

Then, you want `printf` or `sprintf`. `sprintf "%o", $num` will take a number and return a string that is the octal representation of that number, `printf` will print the octal representation instead of returning it.

Together, `printf "%o\n", ord "P"` will print `"120"`.