# Converting to hexadecimal value in Perl

Tags: perl

The following code:

```
$tmp1 = $_;
print "tmp1 is $tmp1";
$tmp1_hex = hex($tmp1);
print "tmp1_hex is $tmp1_hex\n";
$Lat_tmp1 = ($tmp1_hex >> 8) &0x00ff;
```

prints:

```
tmp1 is 0018
tmp1_hex is 24
```

The text file I'm reading the data from contains the string `0018`, but when I convert it to the hex value I shouldn't be receiving `24`.

Comment: That code doesn't output that.

Comment: Also watch out that `0018` is interpreted as octal number: `print hex(0018)` will output: `Illegal octal digit '8'`. ALso `hex` does not convert *to* hex, but convert *from* hex.

Comment: Before typing a code you need possess an understanding what you typing if in doubt read documentation [hex](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/hex.html).

Comment: Is `0018` representation of the digit in decimal or hex form? Number `0x0018` is `24` in decimal form, decimal number `0018` is `0x12` in hex form, base of digit's representation must be know to get a correct answer.

Comment: This was at the very top of a search result on 2022-05-19. There isn't a need to keep answering the same basic questions over and over.

Comment: For output in hexadecimal, see e.g. *[How do I convert decimal to hexadecimal in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481001/)* (though there is probably a more canonical one as this one is from 2012)

Comment: For the other way around, hexadecimal to decimal, see *[How can I convert hex strings into numbers in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531993)*

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert *to* hex rather than *from* hex, use [sprintf](http://p3rl.org/sprintf):

```
my $tmp1_hex = sprintf '%x', $tmp1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `hex` function merely interprets the string as a number in hexadecimal form. Beyond that, it's just a number and its original representation doesn't matter.

When you print a number, Perl uses its internal format (`%g`) to show it. That's a normal, decimal float.

If you want to output the number as something other than Perl's internal format, use `printf` and the appropriate specifier:

```
 printf '%x', $number;
```

You probably want something like:

```
my $tmp1 = '0018';
print "tmp1 is $tmp1\n";
my $tmp1_hex = hex( $tmp1 );
printf "tmp1_hex is %x\n", $tmp1_hex;
```

Note that the bitwise operators don't need you to convert the number to any particular base. The number is the same number no matter how you display it.

Comment: kind of a follow-up question - do I have to convert it to hex (well, represent it as hex()) in order to do the bitshifting? Or I can use the original "0018" string that's being read from the file?

Comment: If you use "0018", Perl will convert it to a number using its default conversion, which is base-10.

Comment: @Igor, Re "*do I have to convert it to hex (well, represent it as hex()) in order to do the bitshifting?*", Quite the opposite. The shift operators work on numbers, but hex is a text representation of a number. They won't work on hex.

Answer (score -1):

The function hex() converts from hex to decimal.  Try something like this instead

`$tmp=$_;
$tmp1_hex=sprintf("%X",$tmp);`

Comment: That's not what you want. He needs to convert a string to a number. Once it's a number, it doesn't have a base. Only representations of numbers have a base.